# Efecto fade en slider

Tags: javascript, css

¿Cómo puedo aplicar un efecto fade en este slide? He intentado trabajar con opacity pero no hace nada.

```
<style>
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto
}
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    height: 275px;  
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #ffffff5e;;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: .6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0
}
.next {
    right: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}
.prev {
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0
}
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color .6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171
}
</style>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
var myTimer;
var slideshowContainer;

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(1)}, 4000);
  
    //COMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
    slideshowContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-inner')[0];
  
    slideshowContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', pause)
    slideshowContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', resume)
})

// NEXT AND PREVIOUS CONTROL
function plusSlides(n){
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  if (n < 0){
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
  } else {
   showSlides(slideIndex += 1); 
  }
  
  //COMMENT OUT THE LINES BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
  
  if (n === -1){
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 2)}, 4000);
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 4000);
  }
}

//Controls the current slide and resets interval if needed
function currentSlide(n){
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 4000);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
  var current = 0;
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

pause = () => {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
}

resume = () =>{
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(slideIndex)}, 4000);
}
</script>

<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="slideshow-inner">
  <div class="mySlides ">
    <img src='slider/2.png' style='width: 100%;' alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides ">
    <img src='slider/3.png' style='width: 100%;' alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides ">
    <img src='slider/3.png' style='width: 100%;' alt=""/>
  </div>

  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style='text-align: center;position: relative;'>
  <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(1)'></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(2)'></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(3)'></span>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede aplicar transición a la propiedad *display*, pero sí a *opacity*, como ya lo habías planeado. El único cambio necesario es en *z-index* para mantener siempre al frente el elemento activo y dejando atrás el resto.

Los estilos con fondo de color son solo para ver que funciona.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var myTimer;
var slideshowContainer;

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(1)}, 4000);
  
    //COMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
    slideshowContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-inner')[0];
  
    slideshowContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', pause)
    slideshowContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', resume)
})

// NEXT AND PREVIOUS CONTROL
function plusSlides(n){
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  if (n < 0){
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
  } else {
   showSlides(slideIndex += 1); 
  }
  
  //COMMENT OUT THE LINES BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
  
  if (n === -1){
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 2)}, 4000);
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 4000);
  }
}

//Controls the current slide and resets interval if needed
function currentSlide(n){
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 4000);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
  var current = 0;
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      // Cambiar z-index para enviar abajo
      slides[i].style.zIndex = 1;
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  // Cambiar z-index para enviar arriba el activo
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.zIndex = 2;
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active");
}

pause = () => {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
}

resume = () =>{
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(slideIndex)}, 4000);
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto
}
.slideshow-inner {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
.mySlides {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 275px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in;
}
.slide1 { background:blue; }
.slide2 { background:green; }
.slide3 { background:orange; }
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #ffffff5e;;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: .6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    z-index:10;
}
.next {
    right: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}
.prev {
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0
}
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color .6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="slideshow-inner">
  <div class="mySlides slide1">
    <img src='slider/2.png' style='width: 100%;' alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides slide2">
    <img src='slider/3.png' style='width: 100%;' alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides slide3">
    <img src='slider/3.png' style='width: 100%;' alt=""/>
  </div>

  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style='text-align: center;position: relative;'>
  <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(1)'></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(2)'></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(3)'></span>
</div>

</div>
```