# Como generar una animación de transición para un slider en html con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, slider

he tratado de generar diversas animaciones a través de css o usando javascript con selección de estilos pero no puedo darle una animación mas suave al cambio de imágenes que quiero hacer, soy junior en programación me y agradecería un ayuda

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            var imagenes = [];
            imagenes[0] = 'img/pastel1.jpg';
            imagenes[1] = 'img/pastel2.jpg';
            imagenes[2] = 'img/pastel3.jpg';
            imagenes[3] = 'img/pastel4.jpg';
            var indice = 0;

            function cambiarImagen(){
                document.slider.src = imagenes[indice];
                if (indice < 3) {
                    indice++;
                }else {
                    indice = 0;
                }
            }
            setInterval(cambiarImagen, 3000)
        })
```

este es el código que use para hacer un slider que cambiara de imágenes, pero cambian al instante y quiero intentar que cambian con lentitud

Comment: Primero define cómo quieres que cambien, define el efecto de transición, puede ser una transición de color, puedes animar la posición de la imagen anterior y de la imagen nueva, etcétera

Comment: Vas a tener que cambiar completamente tu script, porque no se puede animar el cambio de origen (scr) de una imagen. Tal vez puedas adaptar algo como lo de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367070/efecto-fade-en-slider/367072#367072)